# Copying columns with same headers in two sheets but skipping those present just in one sheet

Tags: excel, vba

Following code performs copying whole columns based on headers. Header from sheet2, when is found in sheet 1, whole column is copied to sheet2.

Is it possible to extend this code to skip headers present just in sheet2. Now columns present just in sheet2 are overwritten with empty column. Those are additional info and I need them.

```
Sub CopyCols()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim LastRow As Long, header As Range, foundHeader As Range, lCol As Long, srcWS As Worksheet, desWS As Worksheet
    Set srcWS = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set desWS = Sheets("Sheet2")
    LastRow = srcWS.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    lCol = desWS.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    For Each header In desWS.Range(desWS.Cells(1, 1), desWS.Cells(1, lCol))
        Set foundHeader = srcWS.Rows(1).Find(header, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
        If Not foundHeader Is Nothing Then
            srcWS.Range(srcWS.Cells(2, foundHeader.Column), srcWS.Cells(LastRow, foundHeader.Column)).Copy desWS.Cells(2, header.Column)
        End If
    Next header
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I would store all your sheet1 headers into a [dictionary](http://www.snb-vba.eu/VBA_Dictionary_en.html) then loop through headers in sheet2 checking if they exists withint the dictionary, if so, then copy the column.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "to skip headers presented in sheet2"? This looks to be the bases of your code... Do you want to mean "specific header(s)" which you are able to previously define it/them? Or, you would need to copy  a specific header, if the column contains any values and copy it only after this preliminary check? Can you clarify the above raised issues? In which circumstances an empty column is pasted? If your code does not found `foundHeader` it shouldn't do anything. Am I wrong...?